# Evitar que un programa en Python se quede pillado (no responde) mientras se ejecuta

Tags: python, array, tkinter, ordenamiento, pygame

tengo un pequeño programa en Python que ordena un array de forma visual, el programa funciona bien, el problema surge cuando intentas mover la ventana del programa o simplemente interactuar con la interfaz mientras la animación de ordenación se renderiza y se ordena el array, entonces el programa ignora la interacción con el usuario y se queda pillado, después de varios intentos el programa se marca como que no responde, tengo poca experiencia con python y requiero un poco de ayuda, ya que no sé por donde tirar ni donde mirar, aquí dejo el código.

El programa utiliza TKinter y Pygame para la interfaz.

```py
import pygame
import time
import sys
from random import randint
import tkinter
# Ventana auxiliar para los botones
Botones = tkinter.Tk()
Botones.title("Btn")
Botones.resizable(False, False)
Botones.geometry("200x50")

# creacion de la ventana principal y el array
NUM_BARS = 16

arr = [ i + 1 for i in range(NUM_BARS)]

WIN_WIDHT = 1024
WIN_HEIGTH = 512
BAR_ANCHO = WIN_WIDHT / NUM_BARS
BAR_ALTO = WIN_HEIGTH / NUM_BARS 

COLOR_BLUE = (39, 64, 139)
COLOR_BLACK = (25, 25, 25)

# Inicio de la aplicacion con PYGAME
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDHT , WIN_HEIGTH))
screen.fill(COLOR_BLACK)
pygame.display.update()


def bubbleSort(): 
    """ Metodo de ordenacion burbuja optimizado """
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            for k in range(NUM_BARS):
                height = arr[k] * BAR_ALTO
                xBegin = k * BAR_ANCHO 
                yBegin = WIN_HEIGTH - height
                
                if arr[k] is arr[j]:
                    color = (255, 181, 43)
                else:
                    color = COLOR_BLUE 
                    
                drawBars(xBegin, height, yBegin, color)
            
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
                
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            screen.fill(COLOR_BLACK)
   
    mostrar()


def shuffle():
    """ Metodo para desordenar el array """
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n):
        rng = randint(0, NUM_BARS - 1)
        arr[i] , arr[rng] = arr[rng] , arr[i]
        mostrar()
        
        screen.fill(COLOR_BLACK)
        time.sleep(0.001)


def mostrar():
    """ Muestra las barras en pantalla """
    i = 0
    while i < NUM_BARS:
        height = arr[i] * BAR_ALTO
        xBegin = i * BAR_ANCHO 
        yBegin = WIN_HEIGTH - height
        drawBars(xBegin, height, yBegin, COLOR_BLUE)
        i += 1 
    pygame.display.update()


def drawBars(xBegin, bar_alto, yBegin, color):
    """ Dibuja las barras en pantalla."""
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (int(xBegin), int(yBegin), int(BAR_ANCHO), int(bar_alto)), 0)

""" Botones para desordenar y ordenar """ 
shuffle = tkinter.Button(Botones, text="Desordenar", command=shuffle)
bubbleSort = tkinter.Button(Botones, text="Iniciar Sort", command=bubbleSort)

shuffle.pack()
bubbleSort.pack()

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    mostrar()
    Botones.mainloop()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Utiliza `asyncio`